# Problems with EF-Agnostic design consumed by WCF service.

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

I am trying to set up EF to work on WCF and keeping the domain class models EF Agnostic.

The code is organized into 3 projects. (I am taking a stab a DDD - I am very new to it but am looking forward t learning more)

```
    Project: QA - Domain Layer. Contains the DataContract models/entities.
        References 
            QA.Data

    Project: QA.Data - Data Layer. Contains the context and EDMX (code generation stragtegy = "none")
        References
            Entity Framework/System.Data.Entity

    Project: QA.Repository - Data Access/Repository. Contains the repository classes
        References
            QA [Domain Layer]
            QA.Data [Data Layer]
            Entity Frame/System.DataEntity
```

My understanding is that the domain layer can reference the data layer but the data layer should never reference the domain. The problem that this presents is that my Domain Models/Classes are defined in the Domain layer but the Context which creates and returns them is in the Data layer. In order for my context to know to return a "Widget" object it would need a reference to the Domain layer which defined the "Widget"

**My (failed) solution** : My solution was to create interfaces for each Domain Model and place them in the data layer. The context would return ... IdbSet ... These interfaces would, in turn, be implemented by the Domain Models, therefore keeping my data layer from directly needing to reference my domain (which causes illegal circular references anyway). The domain models were originally contructed using "ADO.NET DbContext Generator w/WCF Support" T4 templates. This process resulted in the inclusion of the [KnownType(typeof(IWidgetPiece))] at the beginning of of the widget class defin ition. (A Widget has a navigation property ... ICollection ...)

The problem appears when I attempt to access the service, I get the following error

> 'QA.Data.IWidgetPiece' cannot be added to list of known types since
>   another type 'System.Object' with the same data contract name
>   'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:anyType' is already present. If
>   there are different collections of a particular type - for example,
>   List and Test[], they cannot both be added as known types. 
>   Consider specifying only one of these types for addition to the known
>   types list.

I can change these to the concrete implementations ... [KnownType(typeof(WidgetPiece))] ... but I continue to get this error because the navigation property they are referring to is still returning an IWidgetPiece interface type which it MUST do in order to satify the interface implementation.

I am trying to figure out how to keep things appropriately divided and still have the context returning what it should. the context returning Interfaces still doesn't "sit" right with me for this and other reasons but I cannot think of another way to do this, and even this is presenting the aforementioned issue. HELP!

Some code to hopefully clarify my previous ramblings ...

```
namespace QA.Data
{

    public interface IWidgetPiece
    {
        String ID { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IWidget
    {
        String ID { get; set; }
        ICollection<IWidgetPiece> Pieces;    
    }

    public partial class WidgetEntities : DbContext
    {
        IDbSet<IWidget> Widgets { get; set; }
        IDbSet<IWidgetPiece> WidgetPieces { get; set; }
    }

}


namespace QA
{
    [KnownType(typeof(IWidgetPiece))]
//  [KnownType(typeof(WidgetPiece))]
    [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public partial class Widget : QA.Data.IWidget
    {
        [DataMember]
        public String ID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public virtual ICollection<IWidgetPiece> Pieces { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public partial class WidgetPiece : QA.Data.IWidgetPiece
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string ID { get; set; }
    }

}


namespace QA.Repository
{
    public class WidgetRepository
    {
        public List<Widget> GetWidgetbyID(String sId)
        {
            WidgetEntities context = new WidgetEntities();
            List<IWidget> objs = context.Widgets.Where(b => b.ID == "78").ToList();

            List<Widget> widgetList = new List<Widget>();
            foreach (var iwidget in widgetList)
                widgetList((Widget)iwidget);

            return widgetList;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want / need two separate models i.e. your data access layer model (edmx) and your "real" domain model? The whole point of an ORM framework like EF is so you can map your domain model to your database tables, using mappings between the physical (database) conceptual model.

Since EF4.1, you can construct your domain model and then in your data access layer map that to your database directly using a fluent API. You can also elect to reverse-engineer your POCO domain model from a database if you want to quickly get up an running.

It just seems a bit of unnecessary complexity to create an entire EF class model, only to then have to map it again into another class model (which will most likely be fairly close to the EF-generated one).

Comment: This design will be the foundation for a service oriented platform so the idea is to detach any dependencies between the Class/Domain Model and EF. The Data Store and Domain Classes must be able to change independent of each other. My training has been that the DATA layer should NOT reference the DOMAIN layer. Mapping the Domain objects to the underlying EF class model, as you suggested, would require a reference from the DATA layer/project directly to the DOMAIN layer/project. This prevents me from being able to then reference the DATA Project from the DOMAIN Project(circular ref. exception).

Comment: Yes, that's all well and good. Just be pragmatic - are you really planning on surfacing your domain model to multiple clients etc. etc. - if so, go for it. Otherwise, seriously consider just putting your mapping in the ORM.

You can always start with a simple EF model for yourself and build a "public" API later anyway.